Error com.facebook.sdk.core - code: 8 When Switching to FBSDKLoginTrackingLimited
Facebook asked us to switch the tracking mode from enable to limited some time ago. I made this change, but I am getting the error "com.facebook.sdk.core - code: 8". I have been researching for a while, but I couldn't find any information to solve my problem.
My objective-c code
-(void) createLoginPopup
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [FBSDKLoginManager new];
    FBSDKLoginConfiguration *configuration =
      [[FBSDKLoginConfiguration alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"user_friends"]
                                                  tracking:FBSDKLoginTrackingLimited];
    
    [login
     logInFromViewController:(UIViewController*)(((AppController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).viewController)
     configuration:configuration
     completion:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
          if (error || result.isCancelled)
          {
              NSLog(@"FacebookManagerIOS - Cancelled");
              
              [self connectionToFacebookCompleted:NO];
          }
          else
          {
              NSLog(@"FacebookManagerIOS - Logged in");
              
              [self updateFacebookDefaults
               :[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString]
               :[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] expirationDate]
               :[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] userID]];
              
              [self connectionToFacebookCompleted:YES];
          }
    }];
}

If I change FBSDKLoginTrackingLimited to FBSDKLoginTrackingEnabled in this code, everything works correctly.
error
I tried the changes mentioned in the documentation, but I couldn't reach a solution. I looked at posts from other people experiencing the same problem, but I couldn't find a solution.
